# jQuery Mobile list view not refreshing after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have an AJAX call that makes a list of things from a JSON array but when the data is loaded there is no visual styling on it and the refresh method is not working.

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
  value = " + data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerName + ">" + data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerName + "</option>" );
  //$("#filters").append("<optgroup id=" + data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerType + " label=" + data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerType + ">");
  for (var i=0, len = data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerType === data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i-1].CustomerType) {
      //Write the customer types
      $("#filters").append("<li>" + data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerName + "</li>");
    } else {
      //Write the customer names
      $("#filters").append("<li>" + data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerType + "</li>");
    }
  }
  $('#filters').listview('refresh');
},
complete: function (xhr, status) {
  $('#filters').listview('refresh');
},
```

as you can see by my code I try calling the refresh method on success and complete and neither are working.

edit: When I add a search filter to the list and type something in it the listview refreshes then but it's not refreshing with the refresh method. And the list is inside a collapsible if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you mean the CSS styling? What does the output look like? What happens when the .listview('refresh'); fires? nothing?

Comment: yeah there is no JQM css styling on it. nothing happens when the refresh is called, it still looks the same.

Comment: Is $('#filters') an existing UL in markup, or is it also created dynamically? If dynamic, call .listview() without the 'refresh' to initialize the list.

Comment: @ezanker the #filters is an existing UL markup and then the ajax call populates it with the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but adding little delay on 'refresh' did the trick for me.

you can do some thing like this in your ajax success callback.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#filters").listview("refresh");  
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jqm listview needs to refresh for dynamic content

so use this code after append

```
$("#listviewid").listview().listview("refresh");
```